# Gmail API - Turn off SSL Certificate Verification

Tags: python, python-3.x, gmail-api

I am trying to run the Gmail API example found [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python). Everything works fine up until I run the quickstart.py example, which gives me the error:

```
SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1045)
```

---

So far I have tried the two commands to disable ssl verification to see if that solves the issue but the issue persists:

```
conda config --set ssl_verify False
```

and

```
set SSL_NO_VERIFY=1
```

---

I have found a general troubleshooting guide for the same [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51390968/python-ssl-certificate-verify-error) and a helpful solution to the problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46566894/ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certificate-verify-failed). My question is, how do I adapt the quick start example to disable client-side certificate verification like form the example by randomir:

```
requests.get('https://website.lo', verify=False)
```

I am running Windows 7 (x64) with Anaconda 5.3 (Python 3.7) and behind a corporate firewall.

Comment: Any particular reason that you need the self-signed cert in your certificate chain?

Comment: Nope, none in particular from my part but it may have to do with my org's setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't really an answer but IT and I were able to determine the culprit to be a patch to a piece of security software running on our corporate laptops. The software has been disabled for now but they are working with the vendor (Netskope) to determine the root cause.