# Getting error "SSLError" while pulling places information using valid API key in python

Tags: python, ssl, google-maps-api-3, ssl-certificate

I have been trying to extract review information using latitude and longitude data for multiple places. I am using python to execute the process. I have valid google places licensed API Key. But unfortunately I am getting error  frequently as `"SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1056)"`. Suddenly code stops and the error pops up as mentioned above. There is no fixed pattern to it. I am unable to understand what went wrong.

I have tried installing a certificate and other solutions as came across. But didn't work for me

The code is giving the required output for some latitude and longitude combinations and suddenly stops by giving SSL certification error

Comment: possible duplicate of [urllib and “SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED” Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835619/urllib-and-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-error)

Comment: possible duplicate of [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED certificate verify failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46566894/ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certificate-verify-failed)